# Error during Deploy test agent in Release Management of TFS 2015 RC2

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

We get the below error while executing Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment task is being executed.  Update test agent is not selected in the task configuration.

```
[error]Error occured on 'QA38:5985'. Details : 'Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer491d645c-0c5a-4e37-b387-18dc78d524ff' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
 2016-07-14T11:09:20.2180363Z ##[error]Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
 2016-07-14T11:09:20.2180363Z ##[error] CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 2016-07-14T11:09:20.2180363Z ##[error] FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
 2016-07-14T11:09:20.2180363Z ##[error]'. For troubleshooting, refer http://aka.ms/remotevstest
```

When the update test agent check box is selected, the below error is encountered:

```
DistributedTests: Task 'DownloadTestAgent' for machine QA38:5985's Error : System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer63061344-35bc-47ed-ab13-4093a853a458' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning] CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning] FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning] ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9388814Z ##[warning]---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."<---
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Task 'DownloadTestAgent' for machine QA38:5985's Log : System.AggregateException: Failed to install 'VisualStudioRemoteDeployer63061344-35bc-47ed-ab13-4093a853a458' from service executable path VisualStudioRemoteDeployer.exe . Consult the logs below:
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning] CategoryInfo :NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning] FullyQualifiedErrorId :Exception
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning] ---> System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.PowershellExecutor.Invoke(String errorContextMessage, Boolean writeResultToLog, Boolean isCancellable)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallServiceInternal(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.RemoteDeploymentHelper.InstallService(String serviceSourcePath, String serviceName, String destinationFileName)
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9488740Z ##[warning]   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.DevTestLabs.Deployment.Deployment.DeploymentClient.<RunAsync>d__24.MoveNext()
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9588831Z ##[warning]---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Management.Automation.RemoteException: Exception calling "SetRight" with "2" argument(s): "Could not obtain the user information."<---
 2016-07-13T14:07:15.9588831Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Failed to copy  testagent setup to test machines. Check if the machines are accessible and installation file is accessible to the test machines.
 2016-07-13T14:07:16.0642158Z ##[warning]For troubleshooting, refer http://aka.ms/remotevstest.
    [error]Failed to copy  testagent setup to test machines. Check if the machines are accessible

[error]Failed to copy  testagent setup to test machines. Check if the machines are accessible
```

Comment: How did your build definition look like?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT The Release is linked to VNext build

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested task Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment on my TFS 2015 Update3, and got a successful release:

[image]

You may try to upgrade your TFS to the latest Update 3, and refer to my setting to create a new release:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, updating the UPN user name format to DOMAIN\Username format resolved the issue.